# Field not found: Form1

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to use a custom made WebPart in a SharePoint site. I made a ASP.NET UserControl and i load that control in a SharePoint WebPart.

I then create a Page within a SharePoint site and that is where i try to add my WebPart.

But when i add my WebPart i get the following error:

> Field not found: 'ReportViewer1.TestReport.Form1'

So i checked my ASP.NET solution and searched for `Form1`. I had a `Default.aspx` in my project which contained a `<form ID="Form1">` tag. So i deleted the .aspx file since i'm not using that for my UserControl.

I recompiled my project, copied the DLL to my SharePoint server. Did an `iisreset`, but it is still showing me the same error when i add my WebPart again. Eventhough my project doesn't seem to have any `Form1` reference. A search in my entire solution didn't showed anything.

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Try to deactivate your feature containing web part. Go to "Site actions"->"Site settings"->"Web parts" under "Galleries" group. Find you web part in the list (you should see this) and delete this. After go and reacivate your feature.

Should work.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Hi, i don't think that this will work for me. I never uploaded the WebPart to the Galleries group. I upload it when i'm editting a page. It doesn't seem to store my WebPart anywhere after i upload it there. So i re-upload a new one everytime i want to test my WebPart.

Comment: Each time you upload your web part it goes to web part gallery. So it should be there. Just check it,